# How to compare two files, but ignore if on different lines (when comparing two files)

Tags: python, list, file, compare, difference

I have this code

```
 with open(newconfig, 'r') as file1:  # New File
    with open(goldconfig, 'r') as file2:  # Standard File
        difference = set(file1).difference(file2)

difference.discard('\n')

diff_file = input("INFO: Select what to name the difference(s) : ")
with open(diff_file, 'w') as file_out:
    for line in difference:
        file_out.write("** WARNING: Difference found in New Config:\n " + line + "\n")
        print("WARNING: Difference in file: " + line)

print("\n\n")
print("INFO: Difference File Created: " + diff_file)
```

but I want to ignore if the file has the same word, but on different lines
so for example

List one:
TOM123
TOM1234
TOM12345

List Two:
TOMA
TOMB
TOM123
TOM1234
TOM12345

Difference:

TOMA
TOMB

Comment: You should split the lines of the files into a list of strings: list1=file1.splitlines() , then convert to set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
def open_file_and_return_list(file_path):
    list = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            list.append(line)
            line = f.readline()
    return list

def clean_new_line(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if "\n" in list[i]:
            list[i] = list[i].replace("\n", "")
    return list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    list1 = open_file_and_return_list(r"path\File1.txt")
    list2 = open_file_and_return_list(r"path\File2.txt")
    list1 = clean_new_line(list1)
    list2 = clean_new_line(list2)
    diff = []
    for obj in list1:
        if obj not in list2:
            diff.append(obj)
    for obj in list2:
        if obj not in list1:
            diff.append(obj)

    print(diff)
```

Comment: and what if i wanted to add all of the differences on a new line? If I am a newbie.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. you want to add the differences to a new file? or create it in the existing files?

Comment: Question for you, if I wanted to also display which line is different, how would I go about doing that? - So it finds the differences, but now I want to state for example this difference was from line 102

Comment: It really depends on how you're file is looking like. I mean i don't really know what data is in the file but if you give me an example i will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a line of text into a set, you can do something like this:

```
text = 'TOM1234 TOM1234 TOM12345 TOM123'
a = set([word for word in text.split()])
print(a)
```

#### Output

```
{'TOM123', 'TOM1234', 'TOM12345'}
```

If you want to find the items that are only in one of the sets, use symmetric_difference.

```
a = set(['TOM123', 'TOM1234', 'TOM12345', 'TOM5'])
b = set(['TOMA', 'TOMB', 'TOM123', 'TOM1234', 'TOM12345'])
difference = a ^ b

print(difference)
```

#### Output

```
{'TOM5', 'TOMA', 'TOMB'}
```